# Is it possible to create a word-cloud of arbitrary shape with Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

I would like to create a shape that would allow me to create a kind of word-cloud with horizontal text in which the overall shape defines a boundary inside which the text can freely flow.

Is this possible with Visio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visio's text area within a shape is defined as a rectangular area with margins and indents and not much else, so I don't think anything like this can be done. If you convert your shape into a group and add multiple text boxes of different sizes in the appropriate places you could make it look like text was following the contours of the shape but you would have to ascertain which text went into which box. I don't think it could be automated.